# Signal Handling In Pthread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, systems-programming

in signal header there was a signal and raise. Signal is used to capture the signal and the raise is used to sending signal to the caller parameter.

But in multithread programming that used the pthread, we can use pthread_kill to be able to sending signal to other thread, but how to receive signal that have been send through the pthread_kill call

Comment: What signal numbers are you trying to use and for what purpose? There are usually better ways to communicate data between threads. Also, you have to ensure that the signal that is meant for a given thread is _not_ received by some other thread.

Comment: We really need to see your existing code. We want an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For C, we would like a _single_ `.c` file [_with_ (e.g.) `#include <stdio.h>`]. But, _no_ (e.g.) `#include "myprogram.h"`. For runtime errors, it should compile cleanly. We should be able to download, build, and run it on our local systems [if we so choose].

Comment: Threads and signals don't mix very well; mainly because when a signal is caught, it is difficult to control or predict which thread will catch the signal.  If you are looking for a mechanism for thread A to cause thread B to do something, I suggest looking into sending a byte over a `pipe()` or `socketpair()` instead, and having thread B react to receiving that byte; it's much more reliable and more portable.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner My personal favorite is SysV IPC (`msgsnd/msgrcv`). Works great for multiple producer / multiple consumer where any thread can send/recv to/from any other thread.

Answer (score 0):

> how to receive signal that have been send through the pthread_kill call

**In any of the ways that a signal can be handled generally.**

`pthread_kill()` differs from `kill()` and `raise()` primarily in how the thread that will handle the signal is chosen.  With `pthread_kill()`, the caller designates the thread (of the same process) to which the signal will be directed.  With `kill()`, the caller chooses the process(es), but the system chooses which thread.  With `raise()`, the signal will be directed to the thread that called `raise()`.  None of that changes how the signal can or will be handled upon receipt by the chosen thread.

When a signal becomes pending on a given thread it will be handled either

- synchronously, via `sigwait()` or `sigwaitinfo()`, for example; OR
- asynchonously, by

  - running the signal-handler function, if any, registered for that signal via `signal()` or, better, `sigaction()`, OR
  - according to the default disposition for that signal

Note well that signal handler registrations are process-wide.  There are various ways to influence which threads receive which signals, but you cannot configure different threads of the same process with different handlers for the same signal.